# Rasterio failed to load VRT

Tags: gdal, rasterio

#### RasterIO failed to load VRT

I use rasterio to load a VRT file, generated by pymodis.convertmodis_gdal.createMosaicGDAL. No problem until recently I reinstalled Ubuntu OS and python packages, and so for rasterio. Now I get the following error when a VRT file is loaded:

For example, I read in the `MOD09A1__2018049__sur_refl_b01.vrt`

```
ERROR 4: HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:/dev/sdf/MOD09A1/MOD09A1.A2000049.h20v04.006.2015136143235.hdf:MOD_Grid_500m_Surface_Reflectance:sur_refl_b01: No such file or directory
Process ModisBaseGraph-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rasterio/mask.py", line 182, in mask
    out_image = raster.read(window=window, out_shape=out_shape, masked=True)
  File "rasterio/_io.pyx", line 330, in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase.read
  File "rasterio/_io.pyx", line 591, in rasterio._io.DatasetReaderBase._read
OSError: Read or write failed
```

The file `/dev/sdf/MOD09A1/MOD09A1.A2000049.h20v04.006.2015136143235.hdf` is a valid path so the file DOES exist!

#### While GDAL-Python can load it

While I use pyModis to mosaicking HDF MODIS tiles as VRT files, I verified  the goodness of .vrt files. To do that, I used python-gdal to load the file and read the raster array. Everything went Okay with Python GDAL. I assume rasterio is based on GDAL too, so I do not understand why it throws exception as above.

```
In [1]: from osgeo import gdal
In [2]: ds = gdal.Open('MOD09A1__2018049__sur_refl_b01.vrt')
In [3]: band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
In [4]: array = band.ReadAsArray()
```

#### Sample of a VRT file

```
<VRTDataset rasterXSize="4800" rasterYSize="2400">
    <SRS>PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["Unknown datum based upon the custom spheroid",DATUM["Not specified (based on custom spheroid)",SPHEROID["Custom spheroid",6371007.181,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]</SRS>
    <GeoTransform>1111950.519667, 463.3127165279167, 0, 6671703.118, 0, -463.3127165279165</GeoTransform>
    <VRTRasterBand dataType="Int16" band="1">
        <NoDataValue>-28672</NoDataValue>
<ColorInterp>Gray</ColorInterp>
        <ComplexSource>
            <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:/dev/sdf/MOD09A1/MOD09A1.A2018049.h20v03.006.2018060011348.hdf:MOD_Grid_500m_Surface_Reflectance:sur_refl_b01</SourceFilename>
            <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
            <SourceProperties RasterXSize="2400" RasterYSize="2400" DataType="Int16" BlockXSize="2400" BlockYSize="32" />
            <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="2400" ySize="2400" />
            <DstRect xOff="2399" yOff="0" xSize="2400" ySize="2400" />
            <NODATA>-28672</NODATA>
        </ComplexSource>
        <ComplexSource>
            <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:/dev/sdf/MOD09A1/MOD09A1.A2018049.h19v03.006.2018060011204.hdf:MOD_Grid_500m_Surface_Reflectance:sur_refl_b01</SourceFilename>
            <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
            <SourceProperties RasterXSize="2400" RasterYSize="2400" DataType="Int16" BlockXSize="2400" BlockYSize="32" />
            <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="2400" ySize="2400" />
            <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="2400" ySize="2400" />
            <NODATA>-28672</NODATA>
        </ComplexSource>
    </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

#### Operating system and package versions

Ubuntu 16.04,
Python 3.5.2
RasterIO 1.0a12
pyModis 2.0.9

Previously when rasterio worked ok I used Python 2.7. I am not sure if moving to Python 3.5 is the main cause.

Answer (score 1):

I learned that installing rasterio from pip while my GDAL library is not in its default system path (`/usr/lib`, `/usr/local/lib`) then rasterio failed to open rasters as it cannot link to the underlying GDAL lib. However by unknown reasons the installation still went well and rasterio can still be imported despite of GDAL libraries not being found.

I decided to build rasterio from source. So unless I installed GDAL into typical places like `/usr/local`, I have to manually config the path to `gdal-config`, and let `setup.py` script knows,

```
sudo GDAL_CONFIG=/opt/gdal-2.2.4/bin/gdal-config python3 setup.py develop
```

Now VRT files can be loaded by rasterio.